# MySQL get sum in nested left joins

Tags: mysql

I've a food listing system. It has five tables.

1. REGIONS
2. BANNERS
3. CUISINE
4. RESTAURANTS
5. RESTAURANT_SPONSORED

BANNERS, CUISINE and RESTAURANT_SPONSORED table records the revenue of advertising.

I want to generate this table.

```
name    | banner_revenue | cuisine_revenue | restaurant_promotions
------------------------------------------------------------------
NY      | 10,000         | 4,800           | 12,000
Paris   | NULL           | 8,000           | 8,000
London  | NULL           | NULL            | 2,000
```

This query will output,

```
SELECT r.name,
       sb.fee,
       sc.fee
       FROM REGIONS r
            LEFT JOIN (SELECT sum(b.fee) fee,
            b.region_id
                              FROM BANNERS b
                              GROUP BY b.region_id) sb
                      ON sb.region_id = r.id
            LEFT JOIN (SELECT sum(c.fee) fee,
                              c.region_id
                              FROM CUISINE c
                              GROUP BY c.region_id) sc
                      ON sc.region_id = r.id;



    name    | banner_revenue | cuisine_revenue | 
    --------------------------------------------
    NY      | 10,000         | 4,800           | 
    Paris   | NULL           | 8,000           | 
    London  | NULL           | NULL            |
```

But how do I get `restaurant_promotions` part? Which is needed a nested left join.

[DB Fiddle demo](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/b9q5WPm6CidwJpu8jm8n2/3)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

modify your query to :

```
SELECT r.name,
       sb.fee,
       sc.fee,
       sr.fee
       FROM REGIONS r
            LEFT JOIN (SELECT sum(b.fee) fee,
            b.region_id
                              FROM BANNERS b
                              GROUP BY b.region_id) sb
                      ON sb.region_id = r.id
            LEFT JOIN (SELECT sum(c.fee) fee,
                              c.region_id
                              FROM CUISINE c
                              GROUP BY c.region_id) sc
                      ON sc.region_id = r.id
            LEFT JOIN(SELECT sum(RESTAURANT_SPONSORED.fee) fee,
                      R.region_id
                      FROM RESTAURANTS R
                      LEFT JOIN RESTAURANT_SPONSORED ON(RESTAURANT_SPONSORED.restaurant_id = R.id) 
                      GROUP BY R.region_id) sr
                      ON sr.region_id= r.id
```

this should work

Comment: I tried your answer https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/b9q5WPm6CidwJpu8jm8n2/6

Comment: @PathumSamararathna thanks for providing sample data, i will correct it a bit later when i have time

Comment: @PathumSamararathna edited, this  works with your sample data